# Sharing DataContracts between java web services (or reuse types) for WCF Client

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, datacontract, reusability

How to provide common data contracts in the multiple java web services (hosted e.g. on the jboss), so they will be generates one time by adding a ServiceReference in the VS2010 and reused in a WCF client.

For the WCF services to wcf client the solution is clear, like it was written here
[Sharing DataContracts between WCF Services](http://www.freddes.se/2010/05/02/sharing-datacontracts-between-wcf-services/).

How to solve it for java web services? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended approach for interoperability is

- Start by defining the message formats in XSD.
- generate the code in your Java web services framework
- and generate classes for use in .NET

The XSD is what allows you to "re-use classes", but the specific steps required will vary depending on the web services stack you use on the Java side.

For some tutorials you can scan http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop - there are writeups on using AXIS2, JAXWS, and others.

Answer (score 1):

You can try contract first development for WCF. See this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335699.aspx). It is not a popular approach. What you can also try is to create WCF service, generate its WSDL and use some tool in java to generate a java class for the WSDL